# Dynamic switching with fxml loading

Tags: javafx, fxml

Using javafx with fxml, and have a design question. I am using fxml to load my main components, so am loading fxml into nested scenes.  The fxml files displayed depends on user action. My question is this:

Is it better to load all fxml into corresponding elements, then just update which element the parent is currently displaying? Or should I load the fxml only when the module it represents is called to be displayed?

Let me know what/if anything is unclear. I'm new to asking for help on my code and unsure if i have given enough info. Any resources or alternate suggestions welcome, thanks!

Comment: "Better" in what sense?

Comment: Well, you have me thinking... I suppose i mean, is there any clear cost/benefit to either approach (preloading all fxml files vs loading each as needed), that would make one preferable over the other, given that my program will need to be swapping between different fxml files?... Does that clarify it?

Comment: There's a pretty obvious memory vs time performance trade off. (Loading them all and keeping them uses more memory, loading on demand takes more time.). If you are not representing your data separately to the UI, loading on demand may make it tricky to keep the UI in a consistent state, though if you use a good MVC approach that problem should go away. But which is "better" just depends on your design goals.

Comment: Okay. I see what you're saying. And aside from that, there isn't anything else to consider? Its just a memory vs. time decision? Forgive my uncertainty, i thought there might be other considerations unknown to me.

Comment: I would do whichever is most convenient in terms of the functionality you need, and only worry about any performance issues (memory, loading time, etc) if they actually prove to be a problem.

Comment: I can work with that. I kept getting stuck doubting which way to go. I'm getting from you that either works until i run into problems with memory or time consumption, or have trouble managing the model data. (And I'm working hard to practice good mvc design).

Comment: About right. I think you're highly unlikely to run into issues with either memory or loading time. Just do whichever seems easiest to meet your requirements. Good MVC practice will make it easier to change strategy later if you need.